# Preventing leftover image files when testing models with ImageFields in Django 1.3

Tags: django, django-testing

Django 1.3 changed the behavior of models with `FileField`s such that when the instance is deleted the actual file(s) remain. For most purposes, this is fine. However, I'm testing an application that makes heavy use of `ImageField`s and I'm ending up with hundreds of useless leftover images in my development upload directory. Since it's development, it's not a huge deal, but I'd prefer to clean up after myself in the tests.

What's the best way to make these images not hang around *when testing*. I emphasize that part because I don't want to modify this behavior across the board, using a `delete` override, etc.

Comment: sorl's image field will clean up after itself when an record is deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I broke down and compromised a bit. I decided to go ahead and use an overridden `delete`, but I made deleting the actual image files dependent on passing a `include_images=True` kwarg.

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    ...
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.pop('include_images', False):
            for field in self._meta.fields:
                if type(field) == models.ImageField:
                    image = self.__getattribute__(field.name)
                    if image.name != '':
                        image.storage.delete(image.name)
        super(Photo, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, I modified the `tearDown` method in my test cases like so:

```
def tearDown(self):
    for p in Photo.objects.all():
        p.delete(include_images=True)
```

I'm not entirely happy with this solution, but it's the closest I could get to what I consider ideal. This should really all be handled by the tests themselves.

Answer (score 1):

A [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron_%28Unix%29) that call to django [command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to find a way to clean up after myself in the test. This is not going to be an issue in day-to-day life. Regardless, though, there's no way to really know which images were created by testing and which weren't from an outside process.

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you call all the test images the same "_test-image.jpg" or something.... In your tests/factories, you can reuse it... Then you can do sudo rm -R _test-image* or something.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue and found this post in Google. I much prefer to use a command instead - so here is some code which might be useful for others.That's in Django 1.4 but should work in any version. I use **WebTest**:

In the base test class:

```
def get_test_image_input(self):
    return (
        '_test-image.jpg',
        file(os.path.join(settings.TEST_FILES_PATH, "images", "test.jpg")).read()
    )
```

In any test:

```
form['image'] = self.get_test_image_input()
```

To clean up afterwards, I simply delete all files starting with **_test-image** in a command:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from fabric.operations import local

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # test an app call "tests"
        local("python manage_test.py test tests -v 2")
        # could use call_command(...) instead

        # remove all test images
        local("sudo rm -rf `find . -name _test-image*`")
```